# What could replace the Traversability Index (TRAVERSE) from previous Fragstats versions?

Tags: cost-path, landscape, fragstats

I need to analyse the **connectivity** of wetlands, I believe that the **Traversability Index** from `Fragstats` is the one that best describes my intentions because it considers not only the ecological cost of different landcovers but also the limit of an ecological budget. However this metric no longer exists in the program. Is there another metric within Fragstats that could perform the same task as in the 4.2 version of the program or is there any other GIS tool?

In order to explain my situation, here is how the metric is described

> This metric uses a resistance-weighted spread algorithm to determine the area that can be reached from each cell in a focal patch. The focal cell gets an organism-specific “bank account,” which represents, say, an energy budget available to the organism for dispersal from the focal cell. The size of the account is selected to reflect the organism’s dispersal or movement ability, and translates into ecological neighborhood size around a focal cell. Each patch type (including the focal patch type) is assigned a cost, based on a user-specified resistance matrix. Specifically, relative to a each focal patch type, each patch type is assigned a resistance coefficient in the form of weights ranging from 1 (minimum resistance, usually associated with focal patch type) to any higher number that reflects the relative increase in resistance associated with each patch type. The index is computed at the individual cell level as follows. The metric is computed by simulating movement away from the focal cell in all directions, where there is a cost to move through every cell. Even a cell of the same patch type will have a cost, usually set to 1, so that under the best circumstances (i.e., minimum resistance), there will exist a maximum dispersal area based on the specified account or energy budget. Note that assigning a (small) cost for traveling through the focal community (typically a cost of 1) results in a linearly decaying function. Moving through more resistant cells costs more and drains the account faster. Thus, depending on the resistance of the actual landscape in the vicinity of the focal cell, there will be a certain area that a dispersing organism can access. This area represents the least-cost hull around the focal cell, or the maximum distance that can be moved from the cell in all directions until the “bank account” is depleted. This dispersal area, given as a percentage of the maximum dispersal area under conditions of minimum resistance, provides a measure of the traversability of the landscape in the vicinity of the focal cell. Averaging this index across cells at the patch, class, or landscape level provides an index of traversability

I would like to create something like this picture from *FRANK, S. Development and Validation of a Landscape Metrics Based Approach for Standardized Landscape Assessment Considering Spatial Patterns. 2014.*

[image: I would like to create something like this picture from *FRANK, S. Development and Validation of a Landscape Metrics Based Approach for Standardized Landscape Assessment Considering Spatial Patterns. 2014.*]